# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't create Engine

Tags: java, android, flutter, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm trying to implement the [`arcore_flutter_plugin`](https://pub.dev/packages/arcore_flutter_plugin#-readme-tab-) and my code is very similar to the example given.

However, whenever I start the app, I get this [output.](https://hastebin.com/onorobeneq.makefile) The line I think matters the most is: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't create Engine`

`flutter doctor` says there are no issues.

Please help, I really need this to work. I've looked everywhere and couldn't find a solution. Thank you!

Here's some more info:

Operating System: **Manjaro i3 18.04**

CPU: **Intel Core i3 (this might be the issue)**

Flutter Version: **v1.5.4**

Android SDK Version: **28.0.3**

Android Studio(which I don't use): **v3.4**

Comment: Are you trying it with a real device or an emulated one?

Comment: In other hand, have you followed the articles wroten by the author of the plugin about how configure it in the native projects?

Comment: @AlbertoSáezVela 1. Yes, it's an emulated device. Do I need to use a read one? 2. Yes, I've read one article where the author helps the reader setup the plugin. I even ran the example given in the repo and got no results. What do you think is happening?

Comment: arcore_flutter_plugin libs are based in arkit_flutter_plugin library .This library has a limitation with the cpu in the device where de app is running. So maybe  that can be the trouble. Try the app in other device.

Answer (score 0):

Filament is a rendering engine used by SceneForm which is used by ARCore. The error is likely due to not having OpenGL ES 3.0 supported by the device (or basically any error related to not being able setup 3D rendering). I guess you're running it in emulator. If this is the case make sure to read [here](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/emulator#configure-emulator) the Section *Configure the emulator to support Sceneform*.

You may also need to install the ARCore service APK for x86. (See section *Update Google Play Services for AR* in the linked doc).

If you are running the app on real HW, make sure you have one of [supported hand-sets](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices).